# Why did the prediction results of Random Forest and Gradient Boosting change into a straight line after a certain time point?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, ensemble-learning

[Prediction results of random forest:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGCFU.png)
[Prediction results of gradient boosting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUsOA.png)

Model:

```
model = GradientBoostingRegressor(
        random_state=123,
        n_estimators=best_params.get('n_estimators'),
        max_depth=best_params.get('max_depth'),
        max_features=best_params.get('max_features'),
        min_samples_leaf=best_params.get('min_samples_leaf'),
        min_samples_split=best_params.get('min_samples_split'),
    )
    model.fit(X, y)
    return model, best_params
```

Predict:

```
gb, _ = gradient_boosting(X_train, y_train, search=True, **ml_searchCV_params)
gb_predictions = gb.predict(X_test)
```

The above are my code for building the model and predicting future data. I can't understand why only Random forest and gradient boosting's predicted results change into a straight line after a certain time point, while other models such as linear regression, svr, etc. lstm and others do not have this problem. I hope to get your help.

Comment: It is worth noting that gradient boosting and random forests are ensemble learning methods, meaning that they combine the predictions of multiple individual models to make a final prediction. This can make them more effective than some other types of models, but it also means that they can be more sensitive to changes in the underlying data. This could potentially explain why they are more susceptible to producing straight line predictions in some cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! " This could potentially explain why they are more susceptible to producing straight line predictions in some cases. "  For this sentence, could you please provide some ideas or cases to solve the problem?